# catkin_make - non homogeneous package - how to figure which package is the culprit

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

catkin_make suddenly complains about a package, but does not say which one is non homogeneous

how can I figure which one is causing the issue ? quiet an obvious feature

I checked the logs, but nothing there

```
CMake Error at catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:95 (message):
  This workspace contains non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build
  a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation.  Try the
  'catkin_make_isolated' command instead.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:67 (catkin_workspace)
    
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

thanks

[edit]

find command :

```
find src -name package.xml -exec grep -L -E 'buildtool_depend.*>catkin' {} \;

src/catkin/package.xml
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346405/catkin_make---non-homogeneous-package---how-to-figure-which-package-is-the-culprit/) by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2020-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-10**:\

> rplidar_ros that compiles fine with catkin_make does not compile anymore with catkin_make_isolated

please do not do this (ie: posting additional / follow-up questions in posts about something else entirely).

This is not a forum, but an AskBot instance. Similar to Stack Overflow/Exchange, it works best when there is a 1-to-1 ratio of questions-to-answers.

Editing in other questions after you've received an answer to your current question is considered bad form and will not help in getting answers.

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-10**:
ok but it's all related, I'll create a new question

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-10**:
so the culprit package is catkin itself ? I dont get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This finds any `package.xml` which does not state a `buildtool_depend` on `catkin`, which would be packages which cannot be built using `catkin_make`:

```
find /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src -name package.xml -exec grep -L -E 'buildtool_depend.*>catkin' {} \;
```

or, alternatively:

```
find . -name package.xml -exec grep -l 'build_type' {} \;
```

(though technically it's OK for a package to `export` a `build_type` with `catkin` as a value, no packages I know do this)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-10**:
And tbh: I would use `catkin_tools` for building large sets of packages. It does not have the same limitation.

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-10**:
I'll have a look, tutorials never mention catkin_tools

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-10**:
No, because it is considered to be a somewhat more advanced tool.

Users just starting out are probably better served by sticking with `catkin_make`.

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-10**:
something odd, rplidar_ros can compile fine with catkin_make but fails to find ' std_srvs/Empty.h' when using catkin_make_isoalted

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-10**:
I unchecked the answer since the 'find..' command finds a lot of packages that compile fine with catkin make

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-10**:
It's going to be *very* difficult to say anything about that unless you provide some more information. For instance: which packages does it list for you?

Also: please show a verbatim copy-paste of the command you executed.

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-10**:
I updated the question

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-10**:
I've updated the command. Some packages have additional attributes which didn't match the regex.

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-03-10**:
ok but do you know why catkin_make_isolated fails to build that rplidar_ros package ? it works fine with catkin_make

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-10**:
I'm not going to answer that in this question. I've explained my rationale in my comment under your question text.

This question is about how to find packages that would make `catkin_make` print the error you quote. I believe I've answered that with the updated command.